# Error when trying to rewrite Python code without classes using ast and astor

Tags: python, class, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a Python script to rewrite existing code by replacing classes with functions. My goal is to achieve this transformation using the ast module to manipulate the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and the astor library for code generation.

I have encountered an issue while attempting to implement this transformation, and I am seeking guidance on resolving it. Here is the specific error I am facing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/my/script.py", line XX, in <module>
    open('path/to/output/file.py', 'w').write(rewrite_without_classes(open('path/to/input/file.py', 'r').read()))
  ...
  File "path/to/my/script.py", line XX, in visit_and_replace
    args=[ast.arg(arg='self', annotation=None)] + node.args.args,
AttributeError: 'ClassDef' object has no attribute 'args'
```

Code:

```
import ast
import astor

def rewrite_without_classes(code):
    tree = ast.parse(code)
    class_replacements = {}

    def visit_and_replace(node, class_name):
        if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
            # Replace methods by removing 'self' argument and adjusting indentation
            method_def = ast.FunctionDef(
                name=node.name,
                args=ast.arguments(
                    args=node.args.args[1:],  # Exclude 'self' argument
                    defaults=[],
                    kw_defaults=[],
                    kwarg=None,
                    vararg=None
                ),
                body=node.body,
                decorator_list=[]
            )
            class_replacements.get(class_name, {}).setdefault(node.name, method_def)

        # ... (rest of the code)

    for stmt in tree.body:
        visit_and_replace(stmt, None)

    modified_code = astor.to_source(tree)
    return modified_code
```

It seems like the error is related to the args attribute when processing a ClassDef object.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: classes are good, why getting rid of them and converting to code to functions?

Comment: For more speed and less code and easier understanding.

Comment: I doubt you will get any speed gain at all, and almost for sure you will not get an easier understanding of the code, since now instead of getting things properly encapsulated you will just have a bunch of functions. Inheritance: gone, encapsulation: gone, clear hierarchy and relationship between Objects: gone.

Comment: I want to give  it a try.

Comment: My code is 700 lines with chained classes and I can't use normal ways to re write it without classes so i have to write my own astor.

Comment: It looks like you posted similar, but different code to the code you got an error from. I don't see the line of code in your error traceback in the "Code" section of your question. How are they related to each other?

Comment: Also, it's not a surprise if you tried to access the `args` of a class and got an error. If so, Python is being honest with you. Classes have no arguments. Their methods, such as their constructors (`__init__`), do. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) list what members each node of the ast have. Classes also can have base classes and decorators.